# Boot of the Ubuntu not recognize pendrive

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb-flash-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 4.14 on my notebook Samsung NP270E4E, I gave permission for 0777 "etc" folder (which I should not have done), then want to re-install ubuntu 14:04 in my notebook, the problem is that I haveI recorded the .ISO file on the USB stick with the help of Unetbootin and when I enter the boot screen looks like this:

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. SATA CD: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SU-208GB
3. SATA HDD: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
4. ubuntu
5. USB FDD:
6. USB HDD:
7. NETWORK

I have changed their positions, but does not start at all the stick. When I install the first time ubuntu 4.14 in my laptop (which was Windows), he gave just right, initiated by the stick. Now it is not.

Comment: If you have got this far, you are booting from the hard disk, rather than the pendrive.  What model is the notebook?  You may need to hit a key during the very start of the boot up process to select the pendrive.

Comment: can you try rephrasing the question so we can understand it a little better

Comment: Notebook Samsung NP270E4E

Comment: edited the question

Comment: it looks like SATA HDD is the internal ubuntu drive, and ubuntu is the USB drive, is this correct? if this is the case, you can try starting the live edition of ubuntu